# “Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match” while iterating through dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I included the code (up to the iterating part) in a Colab notebook [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1G3CrPrQHrm08uhdTO1fJUh5OYuncWA1X#scrollTo=b6zZalRPvHrq). I fed my data to my `train_dataset` like this.

```
batch_size = 30

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_dataset = (
    train_dataset.map(encode_single_sample, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
                 .batch(batch_size) #this one gives the error
                 .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE))
```

I get a **InvalidArgumentError: Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [78], [batch]: [34]** when I iterate through the dataset:

```
for batch in train_dataset.take(1): #error while iterating
```

The `.batch(batch_size)` above gives the error. I noticed that the [tensor] and [batch] numbers in the error message change every time I run the code again. The code runs when I change `batch_size` to 1, but I'd like to be able to change it as well.

Would appreciate it a lot if anyone could debug this part

Edit 1: I'm following Keras' OCR tutorial [here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/), and their code runs just fine.

Comment: This is most likely due to different sizes of the input data (either `x_train` or `y_train`). Can you please provide the shapes of `x_train` and `y_train`? To solve this, one needs to pad the tensors so that they all have the same length

Comment: padding is not compulsory but preferred because of batch optimization.

Comment: I second @rvinas 's request, and may I add that it would be even better with a fully working minimal example (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). In particular, knowing why padding is not an option for you as described in the bounty would be helpful.

Also, the OCR tutorial works fine because all the labels are of the same length if we trust the visualization presented there. Therefore, the tf.data API can safely batch them.

Comment: Use batch_size equal to 1 to avoid this error or use image_resizer to fix this. Take a look at similar [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34544#issuecomment-581446568). Thanks!

Comment: Also take look at this [comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40919#issuecomment-751883479).